# OpenCV CVTrees : double free or corruption on Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, svm

I have a class and there is a member `vector<cvtrees*> vect`. I generate many cvtrees object and push on `vect`. I use this function for train:

```
Mat trainingDataMat(trainSize, featureSize, CV_32FC1);

// fill trainingDataMat

for(int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) { 
    Mat labelMat(trainSize, 1, CV_32FC1); 

    // fill labelMat

    // learn classifier 
    CvRTrees *rtrees = new CvRTrees(); 
    (*rtrees).train( trainingDataMat, CV_ROW_SAMPLE, labelMat, Mat(), Mat(), Mat(), Mat(),                                CvRTParams()); 
    this->rtreesVector.push_back(rtrees); 
}
```

And I use a function for predict. When I run below code, I get an error no source.

```
Mat testSample(1, featureSize, CV_32FC1); 
for(int k = 0; k < featureSize; k++) {
    testSample.at<float>(k) = (float)this->trainInvoiceVector[i]->at(j,k);
} 
for(int i = 0; i < this->rtreesVector.size(); i++) { 
     int response = (int)((*(this->rtreesVector[i])).predict( testSample )); // !!!! THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
     cout << "response" << response << endl;
}
```

Comment: Should I storage objects of labelMat ?

Comment: ok, I solved it. There is not a problem these code, I forget something other parts of my code.